# Finding results that are part of a set with FlexSearch

Tags: javascript, flexsearch

I have an app that uses [FlexSearch](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch). In this app, I have an array of items that looks like this:

```
let results = [
  { id:'a', name:'The title', status:'in-stock' },
  { id:'b', name:'Another title', status:'out-of-stock' },
  { id:'c', name:'Some other', status:'discontinued' },
];

const resultSchema = {
  id: 'id',
  field: [
    'name',
    'status'
  ]
};

const resultIndex = new FlexSearch({
  profile:'score',
  doc: resultSchema
});
resultIndex.add(results);
```

My page has checkboxes for the statuses (`in-stock`, `out-of-stock`, and `discontinued`). My question is, how do I find results that are either a) in-stock or b) out-of-stock. I do not see a way to perform logical ORs with the [`where` function](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch#where). For example, I'd like to be able to say, give me all results that are either in-stock or out-of-stock. From a logical perspective, one could say, give me everything that is NOT discontinued. However, this is not my entire data set. For that reason, I'm trying to figure out how to do ORs within Flexsearch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section [Logical Operators](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch#operators) in the readme. This seems to work:

```
const res = resultIndex.search([
    { field: 'status', query: 'in-stock', bool: 'or' },
    { field: 'status', query: 'out-of-stock', bool: 'or' },
]);
```

Strangely, `{ field: 'status', query: 'discontinued', bool: 'not' }` didn't work when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't using a custom function solve your problem?(found it in the document)
Something like this:

```
resultIndex.where(function(item){
    return item.status === "in-stock" || item.status === "out-of-stock";
});
```

Comment: This will work. But it doesn't use the index - it iterates through each object. So it will be slow on large datasets.